# Using CURSOR when creating stored procedure to insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor

May I ask a question regarding for the SQL Server stored procedure?

Basically I created a table called `Customers` and I want to write an `INSERT` statement inside of the stored procedure where I have been done using CURSOR.

When I execute my CREATE stored procedure should be fine and do not have any error message and also when I execute the stored procedure using EXECUTE statement without any data entry (7, Andy, Singapore) do not have any error message.

Lastly, when I put some data entry into the EXECUTE stored procedure and I got this error messages.

> Msg 8146, Level 16, State 1, Procedure InsertCustomers_Cursor, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 40]
>   Procedure InsertCustomers_Cursor has no parameters and arguments were supplied.

Code:

```
create table customer 
(
    cust_id int primary key,
    name    varchar(100),
    country varchar(50)
);

insert into customer 
values (1, 'John Hammond', 'United States'), 
       (2, 'Mudassar Khan', 'India'), 
       (3, 'Robert Tan', 'Singapore'), 
       (4, 'Dennis Rodman', 'Indonesia'), 
       (5, 'Michelle Chia', 'Indonesia'),
       (6, null, null);

select * 
from customer;

CREATE PROCEDURE InsertCustomers_Cursor
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cust_id    int,
            @name       varchar(100),
            @country    varchar(50)

    DECLARE @Counter INT
    SET @Counter = 1

    DECLARE @AllRecords TABLE 
    (
        cust_id int,
        name    varchar(100),
        country varchar(50)
    )

    DECLARE InsertCustomers CURSOR READ_ONLY
    FOR
        SELECT cust_id, name, country
        FROM customer

    OPEN InsertCustomers

    FETCH NEXT FROM InsertCustomers INTO @cust_id, @name, @country

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @AllRecords 
        VALUES (@cust_id, @name, @country)

        FETCH NEXT FROM InsertCustomers INTO @cust_id, @name, @country
    END

    CLOSE InsertCustomers
    DEALLOCATE InsertCustomers
END
GO

-- This EXEC statement cannot run the query
EXEC InsertCustomers_Cursor 7, 'Michael Labone', Indonesia

-- This EXEC statement can run the query and the results is to show how many are being affected
EXEC InsertCustomers
```

Comment: The syntax is a bit odd. If you have input parameters they need to go directly after `CREATE PROCEDURE` local parameters go after the `BEGIN`.

Comment: Why are you using a cursor here in the first place? Using loops is horribly inefficient and in this example there is no need for a loop at all. But it is not really clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your SP doesn't expect any parameter and you are calling it passing parameters

```
EXEC InsertCustomers_Cursor 7, 'Michael Labone', Indonesia
```

To make it works properly, you need to create these parameters in the SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertCustomers_Cursor
  @cust_id    int,
  @name       varchar(100),
  @country    varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
  ...
```

And remove this part:

```
DECLARE @cust_id    int,
        @name       varchar(100),
        @country    varchar(50)
```

There could be more elegant ways to declare these parameters but for the example I think it's enough.